# Throughput of Hadoop Map-Reduce Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to calculate the Throughput of the map tasks in hadoop but I'm facing an issue.

Can anybody tell me how can I get that?

[image: screen shot of formula to calculate, but I don't know how to get this MB/sec]

Comment: Get what? The numbers are all right there

Comment: how can (2796204.16) bytes are equal to 266 MB/sec?

Comment: trying to get the throughput of wordcount job on a hadoop cluster.

Comment: You have the Map Input Bytes as well as the task's total execution time. To calculate the throughput, you divide `bytes/time`. And the answer is actually `2.796 MB/s`, not `266` for the numbers given, so your screenshot is doing some math wrong

Answer (score 1):

> how can (2796204.16) bytes are equal to 266 MB/sec?

First, that isn't bytes. That is bytes **/ sec**.

Second, it is `2.66`, but using a comma as a separator, not `266`

And, [you actually get `2.796 MBps`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=67108900%2F24+bytes%2Fsec)

```
67,108,900 bytes        2,796,204.16 bytes
----------------   =  ---------------------- = 2.796 * 10^6 bytes/sec = 2.796 MBps
   24 sec                     1 sec
```

Comment: thanks, one thing more, that was actually a screen shot from book, when i ran a wordcount job, it did not show that, can i use the input file size in bytes(suppose if it is 1 GB in case of wordcount job) instead of "map input bytes"???

Comment: The mapreduce output (in the console or YARN) should show you the bytes that are sent to the stages.

Comment: so how can i get map input bytes?

Comment: As I said, it's in the final output of the mapreduce job. Or you can count your input data